# Jquery selects second to last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

An interesting thing has happened as I build an light box using Jquery. I've set up left and right arrow buttons to move through the list so that at the last child the right arrow button begins again from the first child or at the first child, the left arrow button moves to the last child.

What's happening is that my left arrow button is supposed to move from the first child to the last child but instead is skipping over the last child and displaying the photo of the second to last child. I'm not having the same problem with the right arrow button moving from the last child to the first.

Also, when I click the left arrow and console.log the last child, I get the very image that I want to display logged correctly, but the image in the overlay is the second to last image.

```
<body>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="imageGallery">
        <li>
            <a href="images/refferal_machine.png">
                <img src="images/refferal_machine.png" width="100" alt="Refferal Machine By Matthew Spiel">
            </a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="images/space-juice.png"><img src="images/space-juice.png" width="100" alt="Space Juice by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/education.png"><img src="images/education.png" width="100" alt="Education by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png"><img src="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png" width="100" alt="Wanted: Copy McRepeatsalot by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/sebastian.png"><img src="images/sebastian.png" width="100" alt="Sebastian by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/skill-polish.png"><img src="images/skill-polish.png" width="100" alt="Skill Polish by Chris Michel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/chuck.png"><img src="images/chuck.png" width="100" alt="Chuck by Mat Helme"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/library.png"><img src="images/library.png" width="100" alt="Library by Tyson Rosage"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/boat.png"><img src="images/boat.png" width="100" alt="Boat by Griffin Moore"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/illustrator_foundations.png"><img src="images/illustrator_foundations.png" width="100" alt="Illustrator Foundations by Matthew Spiel"></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/treehouse_shop.jpg"><img src="images/treehouse_shop.jpg" width="100" alt="Treehouse Shop by Eric Smith"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $('<img>');
var $caption = $('<p></p>');
var $arrowLeft = $('<button id="left" class="arrow">&lsaquo;</button>');
var $arrowRight = $('<button id="right" class="arrow">&rsaquo;</button>');
var $exit = $('<button id="exit">X</button>');

//Add image to overlay
$overlay.append($image);

//Add buttons to overlay
$overlay.append($arrowRight);
$overlay.append($arrowLeft);
$overlay.append($exit);

//Add caption to overlay
$overlay.append($caption);

//Add overlay
$('body').append($overlay);


//Capture the click event on a link to an image
$('#imageGallery a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");

    //Update overlay with the image linked in the link
    $image.attr('src', imageLocation);

    //Show the overlay
    $overlay.show();

    //Get child's alt atribute and set caption
    var captionText = $(this).children('img').attr('alt');
    $caption.text(captionText);
});

//When left arrow is clicked
$arrowLeft.click(function() {
    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.parent().parent();
            if (li.is(':first-child')) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var lastLi = gallery.children(':last-child');
                var anchor = lastLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
                console.log(lastLi);
            } else {
                var prevLi = li.prev();
                var anchor = prevLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

//When right arrow is clicked
$arrowRight.click(function() {
    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.parent().parent();
            if (li.is(':last-child')) {
                var gallery = li.parent();
                var firstLi = gallery.children(':first-child');
                var anchor = firstLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
            } else {
                var nextLi = li.next();
                var anchor = nextLi.children('a');
                var image = anchor.children('img');
                $image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

//When x button is clicked
$exit.click(function() {
    //Hide the overlay
    $overlay.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1:**

In the handler, you are running an each loop to test each image element, so make sure `return false;` is used when you find the matching image, otherwise your loop runs one more time after a match:

```
//When left arrow is clicked
$arrowLeft.click(function() {
    $('#imageGallery li a img').each(function() {
        var galleryImage = $(this);
        if (galleryImage.attr('src') === $image.attr('src')) {
            var li = galleryImage.parent().parent();
            if (li.is(':first-child')) {
              // if code block
              ...
            } else {
               // else code block
               ...
            }
            // move this to here
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Make sure to update the arrow right handler as well.

---

You have an incorrect variable in your click handler:

```
//When left arrow is clicked
$arrowLeft.click(function() {
    if (li.is(':first-child')) {
            var gallery = li.parent();
            var lastLi = gallery.children(':last-child');
            var anchor = lastLi.children('a');
            var image = anchor.children('img');
            $image.attr('src', image.attr('href'));
            console.log(lastLi);
    } else {
   ...
});
```

Should be:

```
$image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
```

You should look into joining that logic into one handler function to reduce the amount of code.

Also you can simplify this:

```
var li = galleryImage.parent().parent();
```

to this:

```
var li = galleryImage.closest('li');
```

Comment: I know that I need to work on DRY programming. But that aside, the image.attr('href') actually works the exact same way with image.attr('src'). It doesn't matter which one is there. In the revision that I made I changed it so that where it says href it now says src so that when looking at it, folks wouldn't see that and say "that's it, there's your problem". I'm still getting the same issues regardless.

Comment: @JohnCoolidge just helping debug, as in Firefox the image will not change using `href`. I've updated my answer with the rest of the issue.

Comment: I don't mean to sound like I don't appreciate your help. I do. I'm new to JS and Jquery so I've got a lot to learn about DRY programming. I will try and combine them later, but I'd like to get it working before I fiddle too much.

Comment: No worries - the update I've added should help you out.

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much. I actually don't know how to combine these two click handlers into one. I'll work on that next, but the immediate problem is solved and everything works as it's supposed to. :)